# Halt with 50% non-Halting

Tags: popularity-contest, random

Create a program that halts **exactly** 50% of the time. Be original. Highest voted answer wins. By **exactly** I mean that on *each* run there is a 50% chance of it halting.

Comment: What do you mean by *exactly 50% of the time*? 50% is a proportion (no integral number is 50% of 3 times).

Comment: Removed tag *code-challenge* because it needs an objective winning criterion.

Comment: @Howard: I think he means that, when running your program the first time, it should halt, the second time it shouldn't, the third time, it should, ...

Comment: But then it is 100%, 50%, 66%, ...

Comment: @ProgramFOX That would be nowhere near *exactly*.

Comment: I mean that it should have an **exactly** 50% probability to halt on *every* run.

Comment: But then it won't be Halt, Don't Halt, Halt, Don't Halt because with a 50% prob you get runs.

Comment: If the program doesn't halt, does that mean it runs forever? It'll sure as hell halt when I turn the PC off. (Unless it is NSA code, then who knows...)

Comment: You really should clarify your question: “exact 50% probability to halt on every run” is contradictory with “halt, don't halt, halt, don't halt” — there's only a 1/16 chance of that particular sequence happening.

Comment: @Gilles I interpreted it to be out of a large number (say 1,000,000) of runs, half of them (exactly 500,000) should halt.

Comment: @Tyzoid This requirement is also incompatible with “an exact 50% probability to halt on every run”.

Comment: How many times should it halt if it's run three times?

Comment: Who keeps upvoting these poor questions?

Comment: If you flip a coin three times, it also won't land heads 1.5 times, but there is **exactly** 50% probability it will land on heads each time.

Comment: This is a fine question.  Only those who don't understand probability are confused by it.  The original title was perhaps a bit misleading, but no worse than the New York Times.

Comment: I found it perfectly clear.  Create a program that has a 50% chance of halting (or, equivalently a 50% chance of falling into an infinite loop), and you cannot know which will occur before every runtime.

Comment: There is no way to guarantee an exact 50% statistical probability even after doing 1 billion iterations. That's how randomness works.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

#### Perl

```
fork || do {sleep(1) while(1)}
```

Each time you run this program, it halts and doesn't halt.

Comment: Schrodinger's halt

Answer (score 20):

### Python

```
import random
p=.3078458
while random.random()>=p:p/=2
```

Each time around the loop it breaks with exponentially decreasing probability.  The chance of never breaking is the product \$(1-p)(1-\frac{p}{2})(1-\frac{p}{4})...\$ which is \$\frac{1}{2}\$.  (Obligatory comment about floating point not being exact.)

Comment: +1 for maths. This would make a good "what is the behavior of this code" test problem.

Comment: Doesn't work. You can't add up the probabilities like that; the actual probability of halting is 1-3/4*7/8*15/16..., which works out to about 42%.

Comment: nice but the comment above is right: the probability of not halting is P(not halting on first)*P(not halting on second)*P(not on third)*... which tends to ~58%.  See here for exact: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=product+%281-1%2F2%5En%29%2C+n%3D2+to+infinity

Comment: start with `p=0.3078458` to get 50.00002% :)

Comment: My bad.  Probability is hard.

Answer (score 12):

## JavaScript

Alternatives halting and not halting. (halts on first run, doesn't halt on second, ...)

```
var h = localStorage.halt;
while (h) localStorage.halt = false;
localStorage.halt = true;
```

Comment: @Jan Oops, sorry, fixed. (I'm answering from my phone right now so I can't test)

Comment: looks good now (I still like my answer better ;-) )

Comment: Doesn't work on ie8/ff3 (compatibility troll)

Comment: @Tyzoid who uses FF3 anyways? And it does work in IE8.

Comment: This doesn't fit the challenge anymore, because it is predictable.

Answer (score 10):

## Geometry Dash 2.2 Editor Glitch - 2 objects

[image]

**Explanation:**

The random trigger randomly toggles (disables) Group ID 1 or 2 with a 50% chance.

The purple pad is on reverse mode (meaning that if the cube touches it, the cube moves backward, which goes to the left forever and ever.).

Since the purple pad has Group ID 2, it has a 50% chance of being disabled, which means that the cube can pass through it to the end of the level, which will halt.

**How to reproduce this:**

Purple pad is on reverse mode and has Group ID 1.

[image]

Inside the random trigger.

[image]

Comment: Wow GD in code golf

Comment: @Jacob yes!! its a shame 2.2 still hasn't been released even though this leaked editor was usable, even in 2018

Comment: Well, with all of the leaks in the past week it looks like it might be out pretty soon. I wonder what possibilities there are for code-golf with all the new triggers

Answer (score 7):

## C

```
#include <unistd.h>
main() { while (getpid()&2); }
```

Comment: -1: Not Exactly 50%

Comment: It's exactly 50% on my operating system. It might not be on yours...

Answer (score 7):

## [Random Brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), 5 bytes

```
?[--]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0rMS8nP1U0qSszMSytNzv7/3z5aVzf2/38A)

Random BF extends BF's set of primitives with the `?`, which generates a random byte and stores it in the current cell. That is, it generates an integer from 0-255. Given that there are an equal amount of odds and evens in that range, there is a 50% chance that the current cell is set to an even number after the first step.

The `[--]` endlessly decrements the current cell by two, as long as the current cell is not zero. Therefore, all even numbers will terminate. On the other hand, since parity is invariant mod 256, all odd numbers will loop forever, never quite reaching zero.

Answer (score 7):

## [Lost](https://github.com/Wheatwizard/Lost), 2 bytes

```
%@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8kvLvn/X9Xh/38A)

Although this is apparently a popcon, I figure the language itself is adequately interesting!

Lost is a fairly standard toroidal 2D language, with the caveat that the instruction pointer's initial position and direction are completely random. Additionally, in order to make it possible to write deterministic programs, there's a piece of global state called the *safety* which doesn't allow the program to halt by reaching `@` until it's been turned off by `%`. So, this program has three cases:

- 50% of the time, the IP starts moving left or right. It eventually reaches both instructions, and the program halts.
- 25% of the time, the IP starts moving up or down on `%`. The safety is turned off, but it never reaches `@`, so the program does not halt.
- 25% of the time, the IP starts moving up or down on `@`. The safety is never turned off, so the program does not halt.

Comment: Simply brillant!

Comment: @gildux I'm pretty sure this is also the shortest program that can halt at all

Answer (score 6):

## [INTERCAL](http://www.catb.org/~esr/intercal/), 59 bytes

```
DO %50 (1) NEXT
DO COME FROM COMING FROM
(1) PLEASE GIVE UP
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FX0HV1EBBw1BTwc81IoQLyHf293VVcAvy9wWxPP3cwWwukIoAH1fHYFcFd88wV4XQgP//AQ)

`COME FROM COMING FROM` makes an endless loop, but there is a 50% chance to skip to the end of the program.

Comment: [21 bytes](https://tio.run/##y8wrSS1KTsz5/9/FX9XUwF3DSNPF39nf19UtyN9X2ej/fwA "INTERCAL – Try It Online") if you use syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby

```
n = 2*rand(1...49)+1; divisors = (1...100).select{|x|n % x == 0}.count until divisors == 2
print n
```

There are exactly 24 odd primes between 0..100, the largest being 97. This algorithm chooses a random odd number within the range and repeats until it finds a prime:

This particular implementation has two bugs:

- an exclusive range is used, meaning that 99 is never tested, meaning there are only 48 possible values for `n`, of which 24 are primes.
- while `n` was meant to be redrawn at each iteration, only the primality testing is executed in the loop. If at first it doesn't succeed, it will try again - but with the same number.

Answer (score 5):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 3 bytes

```
x;v
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v8K67P9/AA)

I... don't actually know ><>, but this should work on the same principle as the existing answers, just by "rerolling" vertical travel and looping if it goes left rather than down.

Answer (score 4):

## BASH

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
sed -i 's/true\;/false\;/' $0
while false; do echo -n ''; done;
sed -i 's/false\;/true\;/' $0
```

Just a fun self-modifying script.

Note: the empty quoted string on `echo -n ''` are just for clarity. They can be removed without loss of functionality.

Answer (score 4):

### GolfScript

```
2rand{.}do
```

I know this isn't a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) challenge, but I golfed it anyway. :)

---

Alternatively, here's a GolfScript implementation of [Keith Randall's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/17151):

```
2{2*.rand}do
```

In theory, this will have an exactly 1/4 + 1/8 + 1/16 + ... = 1/2 probability of halting.  In practice, though, it will always eventually run out of memory and halt, because the denominator keeps getting longer and longer.

Answer (score 4):

I felt like golfing this one:

#### Befunge - 5 chars

```
?><
@
```

(I'm not sure whether this actually works as I don't have a befunge compiler on me)

Comment: I think `?v@` also works.

Answer (score 4):

## [Poetic](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/), 113 bytes

```
sometimes i,i think i get a choice
if its a thing i know i do affect,i bet i do win
i`m sorry if it breaks
o-h no
```

[Try it online!](https://mcaweb.matc.edu/winslojr/vicom128/final/tio/index.html?HYtBDsMgDATvvGIf0P6pQExYIbCELUV9fermtJodjekU5xQDX4R3rgHiFEdG7coqiQ10C/7bM@xYesUcityaVI@wRPA8F1fiZ8J07y@eFGVLHpb03bH0vks@fg)

Answer (score 3):

Somewhat obfuscated solution:

## Haskell

```haskell
import Control.Monad
import Control.Monad.Random         -- package MonadRandom
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe
import Data.Numbers.Primes          -- package primes

-- | Continue the computation with a given probability.
contWithProb :: (MonadRandom m, MonadPlus m) => Double -> m ()
contWithProb x = getRandomR (0, 1) >>= guard . (<= x)

loop :: MonadRandom m => MaybeT m ()
loop = contWithProb (pi^2/12) >> mapM_ (contWithProb . f) primes
  where
    f p = 1 - (fromIntegral p)^^(-2)

main = evalRandIO . runMaybeT $ loop
```

## Python

The same solution expressed in Python:

```python
import itertools as it
import random as rnd
from math import pi

# An infinite prime number generator
# Copied from http://stackoverflow.com/a/3796442/1333025
def primes():
    D = {  }
    yield 2
    for q in it.islice(it.count(3), 0, None, 2):
        p = D.pop(q, None)
        if p is None:
            D[q*q] = q
            yield q
        else:
            # old code here:
            # x = p + q
            # while x in D or not (x&1):
            #     x += p
            # changed into:
            x = q + 2*p
            while x in D:
                x += 2*p
            D[x] = p

def contWithProb(p):
    if rnd.random() >= p:
        raise Exception()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    rnd.seed()
    contWithProb(pi**2 / 12)
    for p in primes():
        contWithProb(1 - p**(-2))
```

### Explanation

> This solution makes use of the fact that the infinite product \$\Pi(1-p^{-2})\$ converges to \$\frac{6}{\pi^2}\$. This is because \$\zeta(2)=\Pi(\frac{1}{1-p^{-2}})\$ [converges to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Particular_values_of_Riemann_zeta_function#Even_positive_integers)  \$\frac{\pi^2}{6}\$.

Answer (score 3):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), 4 bytes

```
x;
>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/v8Kay@7/fwA)

Comment: Oh, I did NOT see the existing ><> answer... whoops.

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 3 bytes

```
ɹ`ł
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//5M6Eo03//wMA)

```
ɹ          get a random bit (0 or 1 with equal probability)
 `ł        loop while top of stack is truthy (1 is truthy; 0 is not)
```

Comment: I knew these answers would start flowing in once I revived it XD. Our golflangs and tarpits really didn't compare for these kinds of problems back then.

Answer (score 2):

## C

```
int main() {
    char i;
    while(i&1);
}
```

Comment: @JanDvorak Shhhhh, don't tell everyone!

Comment: This abuses undefined behavior that compilers already break [to optimize the code](http://jakegoulding.com/blog/2011/01/27/uninitialized-variable-warnings-and-compiler-optimizations/). Therefore, for this to have any chances of working, you cannot optimize this code (not that this will work even then, because in `main`, the registers are initialized to 0 for security reasons).

Answer (score 2):

## ><>, 5 bytes and a beautiful 2x2 square

```
x;
><
```

`x` sends the instruction pointer in a random direction; If it sends left or right the IP will hit `;` and terminate. If it goes up or down the IP will get stuck in the infinite `><` loop, being sent back and forth between the two.

Comment: it's not called `<><` tho, it's called `><>` lol (unless there's one called `<><` I haven't heard of)

Comment: also you can save 1 byte by removing the `<` (because the pointer wraps around); it won't be a 2x2 square anymore but it'll be nicely golfed c:

Answer (score 2):

**Scala**

```
object HaltOrNot extends App {
  val x = scala.util.Random.nextLong
  while (((scala.util.Random.nextLong & 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEL) ^ x) != 0) {}
}
```

If x is odd positive or even negative, this program will *never* halt.
If x is even positive or odd negative, this program will definitely halt... someday... after thousands of years...
(e.g., if your machine can test 100 Mio loops per second it will terminate after 2924 years in expectation)

Answer (score 1):

### TI-Basic

```
:Lbl 1:If round(rand):Pause:Goto 1
```

Comment: The syntax for `round(` is `round(value,# of decimal places)`, and the second argument defaults to 9.

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 48

```
import random
a=random.randrange(2)
while a:pass
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl

```
BEGIN {
    # Do the following block 50% of time.
    if (int rand 2) {
        # Create a function that doubles values.
        *double = sub {
            2 * shift;
        };
    }
}
double / 3 while 1; # Calculates double divided using /
```

Not code golf, so I could avoid unreadable code (because what it does is more important). It randomly declares a function during compilation phase. If it gets declared, `double` gets regular expression as an argument. If it doesn't get declared, `double` is a bareword, and Perl divides it by `3` endlessly. This abuses Perl's bareword parsing, in order to get parser parse the same code two different ways.

Answer (score 1):

## Java

```java
import java.util.Random;

class Halt50 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        if(new Random().nextInt(2)==0)for(;;);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java

```
import java.io.*;

public class HaltNoHalt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RandomAccessFile f = new RandomAccessFile("HaltNoHalt.java", "rw");
        f.seek(372);
        int b = f.read();
        f.seek(372);
        f.write(b ^ 1);
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac HaltNoHalt.java");

        while ((args.length & 1) == 1);
    }
}
```

This self-modifies the code to toggle the `== 1` to `== 0` and back, every time it's run. Save the code with newlines only or the offset will be wrong.

The `args.length` is just to prevent compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (Node.js), 24 bytes

It was incorrect, but somehow correcting it removed 2 bytes, thanks [Roman Czyborra](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/58925) for pointing out it was incorrect

And another -2 because I forgot how to JS

```js
if(Date.now()%2)for(;;);
```

`Date.now()` returns the amount of milliseconds since the Unix time epoch, which has a 50% chance to be even at the moment of running the program.

Comment: Isn't this missing a final `||for(;;);` to prevent 100% halting?

Comment: I was stupid and didn't think of differences the REPL introduces...

Comment: Can we please stop feeling stupid?

Answer (score 1):

## [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 5 bytes

```
2U$v@
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/98oVKXM4f9/AA)

```
2          Pushes the number 2 on the stack
 U         Pops 2, pushes a random number in the range [0,2) on the stack
  $        Pops the random number, if 0 skip the next instruction
   v       Now moves vertically forever
    @      Halt
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fortran (GFortran)](https://gcc.gnu.org/fortran/), 19 bytes

```
1 if(i>0)goto 1
end
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKilKzNNNT4Mw/hcUZeaVaOlklKanamRq/jdUyEzTyLQz0EzPL8lXMORKzUv5/x8A). Since the lazy programmer did not initialise `i`, it is a random 32 bit integer, populated from whatever bits were floating around in that memory space before.

Answer (score 1):

**Javascript**

JS has these Object URL things, which are generated when you create a file. The hex is all meaningless nonsense, but not in this case! Therefore, something like this works:

```
var blob = URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([""]))
// The blob looks something like "blob:null/01234567-1234-1234-1234-0123456789ab" and is hex, which can be exploited, really, any character works!
while (TextEncoder && new TextEncoder().encode(blob)[10] > 56) {
// Forever!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### Python, 19 bytes

```python
while id(1)>>17&1:1
```

[**Run online**](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhabyzMyc1IVMlM0DDXt7AzN1QytDCEyUAUwhQA)

This gets the address of the constant `1` in memory, and gets the 17th bit from the right. It then loops forever if the bit is `1`.

I can't use a later bit to save a byte, because those bits seem to be constant between runs. The last bits are always `0011110000`.

Some debug code:

```python
print(bin(id(1)))
print(bin(id(1)>>17))
print(id(1)>>17&1)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Exactly** 50% of the time?

## OBJ-C

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification*)aNotification {
    BOOL haltedLastRun = [(NSNumber*)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"halted"] boolValue];
    if (!haltedLastRun) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"halted"];
        [[NSApplication sharedApplication] terminate:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Haskell

Runs for two intervals, each one 1 second long (chosen because 1 second is the SI unit for time). Halts inside 50% of the intervals. So 50% of the running seconds it will not halt, the other 50% it will. Works in GHC only.

```
import Control.Concurrent (threadDelay)
main = threadDelay 1990000
```

Answer (score 0):

### Shell Script

this script will clobber .md5sum files in the current and child directories.

```
#!/bin/sh
echo *.md5sum|xargs -n1|head -n1|xargs test -e && exec rm *.md5sum
while ! find . -name '*.md5sum' -print0 |xargs -0r grep 00000000000000
do {
    find . -type f -print|sed -e 's!^\(.*\)$!md5sum "\1" > "\1".md5sum!e'
}
done
```

Answer (score 0):

### [GTB](http://timtechsoftware.com/gtb)

```
[@r;p;]
```

I know this isn't code-golf but I decided to golf it anyway.

Answer (score 0):

## C++

```
#include <fstream>
main () {
    int c;
    std::fstream fs;
    fs.open ("myfile.txt", std::fstream::in);
    fs>>c;
    fs.close ();
    fs.open ("myfile.txt", std::fstream::out);
    fs<<c+1;
    fs.close ();
    while (c%2);
    return 0;
}
```

Each run will halt iff the run before didn't.

Answer (score 0):

### Windows Command Script

This script will append code to itself which ultimately alternates 'x' on each run.

```
call :last
if %x%==1 (
    echo>>%0 set x=0
    exit /b 0
) else (
    echo>>%0 set x=1
)
:nohalt
goto :nohalt
:last
set x=1
[newline here]
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Math++](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Math%2B%2B)

```
_($rand*2)+2>$
2>$
1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 54 bytes

```python
import time;H=[time.time()%2]
for h in H:H+=[h]*int(h)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/PzO3IL@oRKEkMzfV2sM2GkTrgQgNTVWjWK60/CKFDIXMPAUPKw9t2@iMWK3MvBKNDM3//wE)

Halting behaviour is dependent on current time.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), filename: 7 bytes + content: 0 bytes = 7 bytes, depends on implementation.

- Filename (escaped): `\002.r.w.a`
- Content: empty.

### How it works

- `\002.r`: pushes one of 0 or 1.
- `.w ... .a`: `while empty || pop!=0; do ... ;done`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##nRhrW9pI93t/xTCLZAYISQBbZRhdRdtlV6mrbtcK1CfNpURDAiQoFOhf756ZJAi2z/O@ux8kM2fOnPtttM1o8P0XVHNf1wz7s2kYjmHabm3f2ts1XKNmGZbrvHGd2t6@Wa3tu69@QaOZM/Qq1crQCyqjMPJmXjR8FTkxUp0pmw7N6AHperXKnNkonMTorHV3dHbGW4zE85GDvjixFQZuoSB3VjgcmoFNDzTbedSCqe@j6kHBKBTSyxdH179xnCcpHlJHGQF5RPML8Sk1VslCXeGM7V@d9s3d1fUJr@p6LQNevL9q35x9vGu9v7w8bV1zg3WRGiCcXxwfXf129@H08qr9vtMAMqhfKCyQ1CpEUksmNqVjtlrfuf3ZFWc49c3YQdFAXAhHMayewokdjXwvZqbvmRFSvyAlvzBKOP8rXilcEV@Fdf46O2udn/CGZAFKC4Y2iwaeG0vmNhKIKcCxBiHK/0Ix4sgQrImERAMHbBiHIQp9@6AgvODFyKDMeTR9hHPINf3IwcvlT9DRJr6UQOLMlpFjIyXSZtpcYxH8fNUUyfcr6i@XoLKkBDg/sAVNwAL@I9/fZ@DCkec7hBKX68wyIwc4GBh5ASJukSIXvMGcyLSYGUXO8LM/F44PwedHAVIf46mxjCdIbUVIN6q1@u7rN3v7SOn2gmJfWX6ZOCNUWZpPD0g5Pn3X7ix8YGLz@msG1iWjiRfELlJGF@H7oOO176xWdPX4wX3rnE4un/6e3cw/fr01j@Lr4bl9UlJz@Z0dZfkfWOd1jltdjPI6wn3ewxhM4odPzoREiQgE71i4nNcpRbiHGWZgSEWGBsG4fFXGDUyZEN3lEceYueGEMIh43wsc5B7ojC48l2SAqMl1KvEAGAlLtgoFl3ObLk4JZZIlanWjPls54HUksOTp00B4IlmfEZcKduwl4eREEJLO1NlqtWbzIwPJIblyRiIKAIGxcqeBFXthgM6IJWW3ciAvjWLTeuj6pVKfWxtIcEXg@HSRmAv7qQl8UN1XVZqCEUYpBdXoJ2KAEVYrRbpBfUQhxI6MPJzFQ6JyquABaBeUuNZ9ms2/9jVVMzWhftDUU864YqLjOqokCHiJLRPCGQIbryNb4oGjSULF7GuHGP0KkgUlINcAJQXJUCqk2VqhkAtoasgEQhdTHqgGSyQLDqabvpUOSEVJhEBPWogq5k9lealLIhw2U3kAQ/ou@BckM59DgLI0fXaiXk8Uviw/8ZJ0UWJmpPoxqooyBJSWmRdMrosPRGgefAarAQCUqAgmG4WBFT1O4r5WJGbToCWtW4K0U5N9lYJ/nFnMVtpIWwAZFkF1WEVNg8FfejSA1QAUj7ViLmey1SLiOa3rOqk3mCmM4t31tZLmA9XOWxXYEBN8DwJYYKhuGEQgAAAHAqgNNRWODVhlsrCVARn6Qs3alprK4qLrlfQ@z@tsxMW6JGJyNcp9g@jNtPA1gaZW@3yE3l6haPo5iickr5drlF10VdXr8xtg1iQdnlSDUdksv72itFAAUReAT3AeAwSZ3U6/nNCizHZ8B3pNQoGtOs0a4EeCV0pyvUjliFJaqPsJ9UtA8WZN61mMzkEV2okwApgAOoXWze/0IYAF6yL8gH7gnxkXezbnCUQE9aw5p7MSn6tkzmdQHniWv/e8yu6bgMboKLGA2b2H5GebRoEYI1qvpB3OSvMGuOdwpsI3B98ifHfguzNvQA/6Qe3Tzski4aIDF48lVQKOJQuI4KyBQTpUinlNWxdtCdc@@QjMommiuQm7FLULUqBM@wJ7pMHnM/QxGbLeHQSt60ziYR9MqRWgwmksZlnuAShJZjigC3liCuBKLm2xFN1ItFZ33bdl91REuhGdKstlsreB9MSJp5NAdIiES0kQMG0746qKffQ5zvY5sYfxI9v38gJge48ZYEcihBmBSKsUtb@v3xJcgGIFVnkh2bptJhX0qvvAIc4hF7N@NUj6lQLdPM6KhCLsvVxfXZd2hxzTxUOpxIBMn8OPiBnhtWOgeNwUUHZcKlFYlI9TBFi8IC5EBwZU9mMbQT2iDLIwsibeKOapoKJLOY79DVeg0UxgbJTbzWZ0QU6o0Kf8B6F9fiJlAtG2G1Fi/twfW23s9/UBgoMDY@Poj@cjqc3zyfXWiWAqS8T6/IZc0sUlBzQpiaqmrkeXG0hT0krLN1GNJjT6VrO6@5oethqi9a3R3glaYIFp8E2raILsNGDTQAwJz0TT1bobHub1hrqpy1@CGdxqbcCOyHnWP44auHy@2TUScO65faxvjUg2buTAqHRKbuB34zxMWv7PDwPSLo/LJ2X/GWcx5oAEM5LvBF/iARlTGUVt6A/tJvdZG2JoSsgJT2vsuNwuG5R@w11d3e/jw5NSfa9R3xUDypqNBzJckHfbvO/IeblVvi1/pItzjit3DdQJY1GknC/OBLMWB3x2C2zlgJIMZvU3iWN29@jniWM@iKLY@oY/1bu13X4e08Utr9fVVno5QRGNmewl94w6NKMW5zXRABMkeOvEXjB12ErYP8FuNet7AvFg9w2lEixleOaeMKAf@UdEWiogM@FQdkFuix83dbQ2jH9BrrcNEG0c3mwlwSO45b78gcqqC6bXIePvuQxrcMI92OKDSOByu8/kR4x5YnGf7O9Vtc8/bDpgssFKLCbw4goDf14ogExiFDoiuDJpIFhioYZIApnYtCgiZsuZT8/JBuSgFAFGDkhsyD8jf5bHCUfIZ5piG@xPGVpJgKXAP5vjjYvzf3HxYPPi17VQJLmayZWKv0aMNywxEJVy2/LD5PhBDOEDcJlA2Ty3hWc2UdJWKfDYAxSWLY/JMtUWtbcE9YiI1CmSe/mbVERKE7dxiSL8@cxKNiLB6XcZPCBn6UX2itbUXqNAhgFjQFEFWlM/VNuN9pbnZOvaolh8QVH0snFaDX5PY4VIs4PIvvzyNFryDXTrTMLcOl7GB/7hWPMbvjamdJMr9MP/k@bOT2nuAM0dSVM09@9vO0fnp1zp6Xq1Mqk8VUzlVet95/q0c80V5XvayHBeouFl@ipG7qv1SYr9fGa9ennryUKqBYX3J5d@OFor6oJx10/hjRv/7Z3buUTiGQZTr7KMxP9W1AdkBJOykQ1bn2TBLaIeqRR7NA8zVc8QUwZdYXhSiI7M5SykWkj@82cqEjocisEDgJMfgM9i2nWkdupbCGLiiOA8RCPPLjuxN3TKI2s0LT9GX5ltxg7dVLP@v9WMTc9HalCvZuqAEqTSW@z1VkKZnqEpz68ctWrU39T3aq/re/AegHcHWEVOpckgaiavqH9vZ/F2SuwkPlg8vbJZB2cIY95TxPf95RXEVzariTT3YLDyxIzA4E1CrS4M9@v/QvR6OyEue5BbMDXKgSkdmscI9wJwD9xNenrS0JPGDk@Dy51dnXMj1SxCOIsnNIZL6e1Vemx183o6n//IAh7r0QCp0fd/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Thue](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Thue), 19 bytes

```
0::=00
10::=
::=
10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8koTf3/38DKytbAgMsQRHOBsKHB//8A)

TIO's Thue interpreter doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

## [Thunno](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno), \$ 6 \log_{256}(96) \approx \$ 4.94 bytes

```
2RZw?[
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72sJKM0Ly9_wYKlpSVpuhbLjIKiyu2jIRyoGEwOAA)

##### Explanation

```python
2R      # range(2): push [0, 1]
  Zw    # Random element of ↑
    ?   # If ↑ == 1:
     [  #  Loop forever
        # (Else, exit)
```

Answer (score 0):

## C (GCC)

```c
unsigned long long i,j,k;
r;

main()
{
    srand(time(0));

    i=k=1;
    while (k) {
        k = 0;
        for (j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            do {
                r = rand() % 4;
            } while (r == 3);
            
            k += !!r;
        }
        ++i;
    }
}
```

[Try It Online!](https://tio.run/##XVBLCoMwEN3nFKNQSIgVxWWaS/QGotZOorFEpYuSs6dRqWjfYph5782Hqa5tVXk/mxFb09TQDabdAiYq0YJYQUhfoqGMfAgEjLY0NZ2wb2jGWFAXEqWWuVjT9xO7BqhmsPkXaJCQib18DBaoClwuQMFNAgrgXB07FtTDH7HAhrb1AgYXKMRJd7/lwSShYGf1VGjgEqLIni2veRppfJ@NwfCBNE3jwwy3Z5zjRjvivP8C)

It loops while `k` isn't 0. `k` is only 0 at the end of the loop if `i` number of calls to `rand()` are all divisible by 3. The chance of that equals

$$ \frac {1} {3^i} $$

and the sum of all inverse natural powers of 3 equals 0.5. Of course, `i` doesn't go from 1 to infinity, but from 1 to `ULLONG_MAX`. When `i` reaches `ULLONG_MAX`, the `for` loop will loop infinitely as `j` will always be less than or equal to `i` (assuming `ULL_MAX + 1` is 0).

Since `i` doesn't quite loop from 1 to infinity, the code will loop *slightly* less than 50 % of the time, more specifically

$$ 50 \% - \frac {1} {3^{U+1} - 3^{U}} $$

where U is `ULLONG_MAX`.

Comment: there's also the problem with `rand() % 3` not being uniformly distributed, which leads to the probability of it being 0 to slightly increase

Comment: @c-- True … I'll see what I can do about that.